how can i appear the next item when press the right button and back to old when press the left button

How do I do that or do any dependencies do that?

Try below code with Pageview.builder
final PageController _pageController = PageController(initialPage: 0, viewportFraction: 0.5);
        Center(
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 150,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
                    },
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: PageView.builder(
                      controller: _pageController,
                      itemCount: items.length,
                      onPageChanged: (int index) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentPage = index;
                        });
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return _buildItem(index);
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _pageController.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.ease);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),

